# how to remove old li in my carousel

Tags: jquery, slideshow, carousel

this is a my carousel [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oneng/8rNbZ/3/)

problem in old li, me need to delete previous li

js code:

```
$('.conrollers .prev').click(function () {
    slide_prev();
});
$('.conrollers .next').click(function () {
    slide_next();
});

function slide_prev() {
    $('ul .slide.visible').prev().addClass('visible').addClass('visible').next().next().removeClass('visible');
    $('ul .slide').clone().insertBefore(".slide.first").removeClass('first').removeClass('visible').first().addClass('first');
}

function slide_next() {
    $('ul .slide.visible').next().addClass('visible').next().addClass('visible').prev().prev().removeClass('visible');
    $('.slide').clone().addClass('no_remove_this').insertAfter(".slide.visible.last").removeClass('last').removeClass('visible').last().addClass('last');

}

var timer_li = setInterval(slide_next, 1000);

    $('.side').mouseover(function(){
        clearInterval(timer_li);
    }).mouseout(function(){
        timer_li = setInterval(slide_next, 1000);
    })


$('ul .slide').first().addClass('visible');
$('ul .slide').first().next().addClass('visible');

$('ul .slide:first-child').addClass('first');
$('ul .slide:last-child').addClass('last');




$('ul .slide').first().addClass('visible');
$('ul .slide').first().next().addClass('visible');
```

class .no_remove_this i added becouse think this can help me for remove all li.slide something like this:

```
:not(.no_remove_this);
```

Can somebody help me?)

Thanks!)

**updated [carousel-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oneng/dhqRn/6/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned it up a little bit, but the code could be vastly improved.

http://jsfiddle.net/8rNbZ/11/

removed all the

```
 .clone()
```

and re-used the dom elements instead